# Slim Framework - HTTP GET request with string that contains forward slash

Tags: php, slim

I'm using the Slim Framework to create some web services, to make a search by keyword in my web application. My problem is that when I search by keyword that have a forward slash (/), the slim interprets the slash as a route and the response is a `404 not found`.

For example if my keyword is: "One" an HTTP GET request for `/events/One` will invoke the associated callback function, passing "One" as the callback's argument. But if my keyword is: "One/Two", an HTTP GET request for `/events/One/Two` will invoke the associated callback function, because the Slim expects a route like this `events/:parm1/parm2`.

How can I solve this?

```
$app->get('/eventos/genero/:genero', 'findByGenero');

function findByGenero($genero) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, id_organizador, imagem, titulo, latitude, longitude, endDate, startDate, local, rua FROM eventos_sapo WHERE genero LIKE :genero ORDER BY titulo";
    try {
        $db = getConn();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $genero = "%".$genero."%";
        $stmt->bindParam("genero", $genero);
        $stmt->execute();
        $eventos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($eventos);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: urlencode the string before searching for it.

Answer (score 0):

If url encoding the parameter does'nt work then you could use a query paraemter rather than a route parameter:

```php
$app->get('/eventos/genero', 'findByGenero');

function findByGenero() {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    $genero = $app->request->get('q');

    if ($genero) {
        $sql = "SELECT id, id_organizador, imagem, titulo, latitude, longitude, endDate, startDate, local, rua FROM eventos_sapo WHERE genero LIKE :genero ORDER BY titulo";
        try {
            $db = getConn();
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $genero = "%".$genero."%";
            $stmt->bindParam("genero", $genero);
            $stmt->execute();
            $eventos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $db = null;
            echo json_encode($eventos);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
        }
    }
}
```

The URL is now: `/eventos/genero?q=2134`